# Makefile not copying binary code properly

Tags: windows, makefile, command, mingw

I'm working on making a simple operating system (for fun) but I've stumbled upon a rather peculiar problem that I cannot find how to fix.

When I attempt to concatenate kernel.bin to boot/boot_sect.bin and save the result in os-image, it appears that it copies the assembly code instead, but the kernel.bin file is concatenated as expected. However boot/boot_sect.bin does exist and does contain the correct binary data, as I demonstrate below.

When I copied boot/boot_sect.bin to boot_sect_real.bin using the Windows 10 File Explorer, and then run the same command but on boot_sect_real.bin instead, everything works as expected. So it appears to have something to do with either boot_sect.bin being in a directory, or boot_sect.bin and boot_sect.asm being in the same directory. I'm also using MinGW to use a Makefile
(with mingw32-make)

This is the Makefile, with the os-image command highlighted using comments:

```
C_SOURCES = $(wildcard kernel/*.c drivers/*.c)
HEADERS = $(wildcard kernel/*.h drivers/*.h)

OBJ = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}

all: os-image

########################################
os-image: boot/boot_sect.bin kernel.bin
    copy /b $<+kernel.bin os-image
########################################

%.o : %.c ${HEADERS}
    gcc -ffreestanding  -c $< -o $@

%.o : %.asm
    nasm $< -f elf -o $@

%.bin : %.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@

kernel.bin: kernel/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    ld -T NUL -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 $^
    objcopy -O binary -j .text kernel.tmp kernel.bin
```

This is what the directory that I'm running all this in looks like:
[image]

This is the contents of the boot directory:
[image]

And this is the contents of the kernel directory:
[image]

(the drivers directory is empty right now)

This is the contents of the kernel.bin file:
[image]

And this is the contents of the boot/boot_sect.bin file:
[image]

However the os-image file contains the assembly code?
[image]

(I am using the copy command with /b)

Is there any way I can concatenate the binary contents of kernel.bin to boot/boot_sect.bin and save the result in os-image? What's going wrong?

UPDATE: I found this happening, if it's worth anything:
[image]
It's using the .asm file even though I specified .bin in the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I certainly feel dumb now.

I changed

copy /b boot/boot_sect.bin+kernel.bin os-image

to

copy /b boot\boot_sect.bin+kernel.bin os-image

It was a simple character replacement away!

Comment: Almost all windows programs will accept either style of slash.  However, the old command.com shell programs mostly do not allow forward slashes and you MUST use backslashes.